# Picker view hiding corresponding text field

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I create multiple UITextFields in my storyboard. Some text field are edited using keyboard while others using picker view. In my view controller, for the fields using pickerView, I created separate picker views for each of the text fields. For eg.

```
aTextField.inputView = aPickerView
```

Now for the text fields which are at the bottom of the screen, when I tap on one of them, picker view corresponding to that text field opens at the bottom and it hides the textfield. I want to shift the currently selected text field up when the picker view opens.
In case of keyboard, shifting of views can be done by responding to `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification`. How to do this in case of picker view?

Comment: "which are at the bottom of the screen"  We don't see them in code or graphically.

Comment: Use keyboard 3rd party for easy: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is observing keyboard height. When you press the picker view that has to show up the bottom textField, use keyboard height and some extra points to move it over the keyboard. Here are some helper methods to achieve that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Add keyboard observers
addObservers()
}

private func addObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// keyboard will be active
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    // Get keyboard Size
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        // update constraints / footerview height with keyboard height "keyboardSize.height"
    }
}

    // keyboard will dismiss
@objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue != nil {
     // update constraints / footerview height when keyboard is hidden,

    }
}
```